# Кодирование методом перестановки

Tags: delphi

Кодирует все правильно, но не учитывает чего-то пробелы. Например, 
слова: абв абв
Ключ: 7654321 
Результат: вбавба 
а должно быть: вба вба.

```
function encode(st,k:string):string;
var i,j:byte;
buf:string;
res:string;
begin
res:='';
while Length(k)<=Length(st) do  begin
buf:=Copy(st,1,Length(k));
delete(st,1,Length(k));
for I := 1 to length(k) do
res:=res+buf[strtoint(k[i])];
end;
if trim(st)<>'' then
begin
  while length(st)<Length(k) do
  st:=st+' ';
for I := 1 to length(k) do
res:=res+buf[strtoint(k[i])];
end;
while pos(' ',res)<>0  do delete(res,pos(' ',res),1);
result:=res;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  key:string;
    s :string;
    begin
  s:=memo1.text;
  key:=edit2.text;
memo2.text:=encode(s,key);

end;
```

Answer (score 7):

А вас не смущает вот эта строчка в конце функции encode?

```
while pos(' ',res)<>0  do delete(res,pos(' ',res),1);
```

И вам стоить чуть больше уделять форматированию кода. Код в таком виде как ваша функция encode мягко говоря "малочитаем".

Comment: значит ее нужно убрать?

Comment: большое спасибо помогло)